# Find unique array of objects dynamically considering undefined values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, ecmascript-5

I have a an array of objects in this format:

```
const myArray = [
 {
  one: 'A',
  two: 'AB'
 },
 {
  one: undefined,
  two: 'AB'
 },
 {
  one: 'A',
  two: 'BC'
 },
 {
  one: undefined,
  two: 'CC'
 },
]
```

I want the output in this particular format where if one is undefined but two is present in another object then ignore that object.
e.g., output:

```
const outputMyArray = [
 {
  one: 'A',
  two: 'AB'
 },
 {
  one: 'A',
  two: 'BC'
 },
 {
  one: undefined,
  two: 'CC'
 },
```

The object keys are dynamically generated hence cannot be hardcoded and each object can have same numbers of keys as others.
This I have tried but did not work:

```
const objectValuesList = myArray.map((obj: any) => Object.values(obj))

const uniqueStrigifiedList = Array.from(new Set( objectValuesList.filter((obj: any) => !obj.includes(undefined)).map((obj: any) => JSON.stringify(obj)) ))

myArray?.filter((obj: any) => !uniqueStrigifiedList?.includes( String(Object.values(obj)) ))
```

This solution does not seem to be working as it considers all object keys as unique.

Comment: im not quite sure i understand. why cant you use filter on outputMyArray directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a two step approach:

1. Get all object with no `undefined` as value and store the values with to an object.
2. Check the objects with `undefined` and if not seen add this object to the result array.

```js
const
    data = [{ one: 'A', two: 'AB' }, { one: undefined, two: 'AB' }, { one: 'A', two: 'BC' }, { one: undefined, two: 'CC' }],
    keys = ['one', 'two'],
    result = [],
    seen = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, {}])),
    withUndefined = [];

for (const o of data) {
    if (keys.every(k => o[k] !== undefined)) {
        keys.forEach(k => seen[k][o[k]] = true);
        result.push(o);
    } else {
        withUndefined.push(o);
    }
}

for (const o of withUndefined) {
    if (keys.some(k => seen[k][o[k]])) continue;
    result.push(o);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable with one filter:

- If there is no `one`,

  - and if there isn't any other element in the array with the same `two` and a non-undefined `one`,

    - then it fails the filter (removed)
    - else, it passes (kept)
- Otherwise, it passes the filter (kept)

```js
const myArray=[{one:'A',two:'AB'},{one:undefined,two:'AB'},{one:'A',two:'BC'},{one:undefined,two:'CC'},];

const output = myArray.filter((value) => !value.one ? !myArray.some((other) => other !== value && other.two === value.two && other.one) : true);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked with me

```
const outputMyArray = myArray.filter((obj, index) => {
    if (!obj.one) {
        let flag = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (index == i) continue;
            if (obj.two == myArray[i].two) flag = false;
        }
        return flag
    } else return true
});
```

Maybe it isn't the best practices but I tried to help

Comment: You should `return true` instead of `return obj`, and an explicit `return false` would be nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define the type to indicate the shape of the objects
const myArray: Array<Record<string, string | undefined>> = [
    { one: 'A', two: 'AB' },
    { one: undefined, two: 'AB' },
    { one: 'A', two: 'BC' },
    { one: undefined, two: 'CC'},
]

const outputMyArray = myArray.filter(obj => {
    // Get the keys for each object
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);

    // What would you do in the case of empty objects?
    if (keys.length === 0) { 
        return false;
    } else {
        // Using 'for of' loop to get each key value for each object within the array.
        for (const key of keys) {
            if (obj[key] === undefined) {
                // once there's one undefined key 
                return false; 
            } 
        }
        // All the keys were not undefined
        return true;
    }
})

console.log(outputMyArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the array to a new array. For each object in the array check for a matching object in the accumulator (`acc`), and if found replace it. If not, add the current item to the accumulator:

```js
const { isMatchWith, isUndefined } = _

const data = [{ one: 'A', two: 'AB' }, { one: undefined, two: 'AB' }, { one: 'A', two: 'BC' }, { one: undefined, two: 'CC' }]

// match if values are identical or if the 2nd value is undefined
const isMatchWithUndefined = (o1, o2) => 
  isMatchWith(o1, o2, (_, v2) => isUndefined(v2) || undefined)

// find and return the best match (less undefined) and the index
const findMatch = (arr, o1) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const o2 = arr[i]
    if(isMatchWithUndefined(o1, o2)) return [o1, i]
    if(isMatchWithUndefined(o2, o1)) return [o2, i]
  }
  
  return [null, -1]
}

const result = data.reduce((acc, o) => {  
  const [match, index] = findMatch(acc, o)
  
  if(match) acc[index] = match // if there's a match set the match at the index
  else acc.push(o) // if not add the item to the accumulator
  
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```